# Android Studio: when I run the app I got this error

Tags: android, android-multidex

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Pictures/trackings/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/manifest_keep.txt (No such file or directory)

When I run my app in my IDE, I get this error.

In manifest.xml I added this line:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Comment: clean app and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Create multidex file and write following code in app gradle

```
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexKeepFile file 'multidex-config.txt'

    }
  }
}
```

[Refer this documentation for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)